# Using output of diff -e with sed

Tags: sed, diff

I'm currently attempting to change the contents of one file

```
orig.sas
```

to match the contents of an updated file

```
new.sas
```

Replacing orig.sas with new.sas makes some of the changes, but there are many directories referenced within orig.sas that I do not want altered.

Submitting the following code outputs a script 'changes.txt' with all of the lines needed to be altered in orig.sas to make it identical to new.sas

```
diff -e orig.sas new.sas > changes.txt
```

changes.txt looks like this (full output has many more lines):

```
3668c
label DBMS=xlsx replace;
.
3649,3665d
3643d
```

From here I have removed all lines which reference changes in directories, so only the body of the code is affected.

I think I should be able to submit this script into sed (with the aim of making all of the changes changes.txt) using something like:

```
sed - orig.sas < changes.txt
```

But I don't want to directly overwrite the orig.sas, instead preferring to output to a version 2 file (eg. orig_v2.sas)

My progress to this point has come from instruction from https://www.computerhope.com/unix/udiff.htm

Comment: we can help you out please post the sample input and expected output with clear explaination

Comment: The instructions you are following seem to be about creating and running an `ed` script, not a `sed` script - while superficially similar, there are going to be some differences. You might be able to do what you want using `ed` as described there but replacing the step `echo "w" >> my-ed-script.txt` with `echo "w orig_v2.sas" >> my-ed-script.txt`.

Comment: @steeldriver thank you very much for your solution! You were completely right, instructing ed to write to a newly named file was exactly what was needed. Very elegant, thank you! (I'm not sure how to give you the credit for your answer with a tick or vote)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`diff -e` 's result is supposed to be feed (modified) to `ed`.

try

```
diff -e orig.sas new.sas > changes.txt
echo wq >> changes.txt

ed orig.sas < changes.txt
```

where

- `wq` will **w**rite and **q**uit, printing number of char written
- optional `--silent` will not output above count.

see `man ed` for further information.

## edit

I fail to see point in diffing to apply diff to original file, it looks to me that `cp new.sas orig_v2.sas` would do

I suppose you have this in mind : two branch `alpha`N and `bravo`N

```
diff -e alpha1.sas alpha2.sas > change12.txt

(cat change12.txt
 echo w bravo2.sas
 echo q ) | ed bravo.sas
```

this will report on `bravo`N changes made to `alpha`N

Comment: Thank you for your reply! The extra steps and suggestions are really appreciated. You are correct that copying the original file and then modifying it would work. 
The reason I was looking to write to a new output file (as in steeldriver's comment) is this is a process I'll likely perform regularly and want to reduce the chance of errors through fewer steps. 
I really like your suggestion of creating a changelog so will likely use that for auditing purposes. Thank you!